# Pass table row textbox values from View to Controller in ASP.net MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="ctrName" asp-action="Index" >
<input type="text" class="form-control >               
                    <button type="submit" > Search                       
                    </button>
 @if (Model != null)
    {        
               <table class="table" border="1">
                    <thead style="font-size:90%;">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ecuType)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.exp)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ecuSft)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.newSerialNumber)                  
                    </th>
                    <th>Download</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ecuType)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.exp)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ecuSft)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                             @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.newSerialNumber)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                        <a href="@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "TemDownload", new { newSerialNumber = item.newSerialNumber })" class="button">Download</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
    </table>                
            
    <form>
```

On initial page load NewSerialNumber is null. On each row Download button click I need to pass entered NewSerialNumber textbox value from view to controller. Currently it is passing null value to controller action method. Based on the passed value it will download specific file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So what issue you are having here? Aren't you are getting the ID in your controller? Could you please include your controller code as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    I am making an ajax call and below solution is working for me.
    
    @model IEnumerable<DotNet6MVCWebApp.Controllers.DemoModelClass>
    <form method="post" asp-controller="ctrName" asp-action="Index">
        <input type="text" class="form-control >
        <button type="submit">
            Search
        </button>
        <table class="table" border="1">
            <thead style="font-size:90%;">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ecuType)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.exp)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ecuSft)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.newSerialNumber)
                    </th>
                    <th>Download</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ecuType)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.exp)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ecuSft)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.newSerialNumber)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="download-button" data-textbox-value="@item.newSerialNumber"> Download</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>  
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){    
        $(".download-button").click(function(){
        var engineModel = $(this).data("column1");
        var ecuType = $(this).data("column2");
                var engineSerialNumber = $("#SearchString").val();
        var newSerialNumber = $(this).closest("tr").find(".textbox").val();
$.ajax({
                url: '/ctrName/DownloadFile',
                type: 'POST',
                data:{                   
                    newSerialNumber: newSerialNumber
                },
                success: function(){
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error){                  
                    
                }
    });
      });        
        });    
    </script>
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

> On each row Download button click I need to pass NewSerialNumber
> textbox value from view to controller. Currently it is passing null
> value to controller action method based on the passed value it will
> download specific file.

Well, seems you are trying to pass your `TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.newSerialNumber)` value from view to your controller once the button clicked. But sending that as new parameter object `new { newSerialNumber = item.newSerialNumber }` would always pass the null value and this not the correct way. Because, `@Url.Action` doesn't have the overload for controller, action and the parameter together. As you can see below:

[image]

However, instead of passing new object you can use [asp-route-{value}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0#asp-route-value) attribute and pass the your newSerialNumber as route id that can meet your requirement. If its within the same controller, you just need to pass the route parameter which is your controller action's method argument or parameter.

So in order to pass our textbox value to the controller action, you can do as following:

Demo Model:

```
public class DemoModelClass
    {
        public string ecuType { get; set; }
        public string exp { get; set; }
        public string ecuSft { get; set; }
        public int newSerialNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller Action For Loading View:

```
public IActionResult SaveIndex()
        {
            var demoList = new List<DemoModelClass>()
            {
                new DemoModelClass(){ newSerialNumber = 1001,ecuType  ="ecuType-A",exp  ="exp-X", ecuSft = "ecuSft-P"},
                new DemoModelClass(){ newSerialNumber = 1002,ecuType  ="ecuType-B",exp  ="exp-Y", ecuSft = "ecuSft-Q"},
                new DemoModelClass(){ newSerialNumber = 1003,ecuType  ="ecuType-C",exp  ="exp-Z", ecuSft = "ecuSft-R" }

            };
            return View(demoList);
        }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<DotNet6MVCWebApp.Controllers.DemoModelClass>
<form method="post" asp-controller="ctrName" asp-action="Index">
    <input type="text" class="form-control >
    <button type="submit">
        Search
    </button>
    <table class="table" border="1">
        <thead style="font-size:90%;">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ecuType)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.exp)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ecuSft)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.newSerialNumber)
                </th>
                <th>Download</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ecuType)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.exp)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ecuSft)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.newSerialNumber)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="DownloadFile" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-newSerialNumber="@item.newSerialNumber">Download</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Controller Action:

```
public IActionResult DownloadFile(int newSerialNumber)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0#asp-route-value), if you want to study more on [how asp-route arrtibute works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0#asp-route-value).

**Upadated Answer:**

After reading your comment, I would like to explain few thing.  Actually, razor page doesn't work the way you are assuming, while you would load the view it will bind list with relevant model, so if the textbox populated as empty razor cannot recognizes the change in DOM unless you would use javascript, so in order to achieve your requirement, you can write a js function and call the controller using ajax reuqest and pass your textbox value. I have updated the  answer please have a try.

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Model.DemoModelClass>
<form method="post" asp-controller="ctrName" asp-action="Index">
    <input type="text" class="form-control >
    <button type="submit">
        Search
    </button>
    <table class="table" border="1">
        <thead style="font-size:90%;">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ecuType)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.exp)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ecuSft)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.newSerialNumber)
                </th>
                <th>Download</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ecuType)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.exp)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ecuSft)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="newSerialNumber" id="newSerialNumber" class="form-control" />
                        
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Download()">Download</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>


@section Scripts {
    <script>
        function Download() {

            var newSerialNumber = $("#newSerialNumber").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'http://localhost:5094/ControllerName/DownloadFile?newSerialNumber='+ newSerialNumber,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (response) {
                }
            });
            
        }
    </script>
}
```

**Note:** Update your the request URL with correct controller and action name.

Ouput:

[image]

Comment: Initially newSerialNumber is null when we load the grid. From the View I need to pass entered newSerialNumber value to controller. I tried this  and it is still passing null value.

Comment: Hi Kamini, thanks for your update, I got your point, actually, razor page doesn't work this way, while you would load the view,  it will bind list with relevant model and value, so if the textbox populated as empty razor cannot recognize the change unless you would use javascript, so in order to achieve your requirement, you can write a js function and call the controller using ajax request and pass your textbox value. I have updated the answer please have a try.